# How to get filepath?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, url, tomcat

I am working on an Eclipse Web Dynamic Project, and trying to access a file that exists in my local machine/server.

What I am looking for is something like "base_url()" in CodeIgniter, which automatically points to the directory the server is located.

I am using a Mac.

```
try{
          model.read(new FileInputStream(url),"");
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
          System.out.println("Exception caught"+e.getMessage());
      }
```

This is the part of the code I am working on, which I am trying to feed the correct URL path to read.

After searching StackOverflow and other places, I came across this piece of code:

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI().substring(1), request.getContextPath())
            +"/WebContent/WEB-INF/test.xml";
```

Which did not seem to work.

I then tried to hard code the path directory in, only to realise that I dont know how Mac file systems work :/

Can anyone share some light on this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There might be `FileSeperator` problem.

Comment: In Linux file seperator is '/' where as in windows machine it is '\'. So that might be this problem.

Comment: it generates this: http:/localhost:8080/iWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/test.xml, which for some reason, is wrong. Though it is right no matter how i look at it.

Comment: So there is not file seperator problem as the web url will be having same file path seperator '/'

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand very well if you are using a `servlet` or something else (like a WS), however the `request` object exposes a method called `getRealPath()` which gives well... the real path of the servlet's context in your file system.

So you need to change your code with this:

```
String url = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/test.xml";
```

It has nothing to do with OS, as you surely know java is portable.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

which point to the bas directory of your application in the server

```
e.g. /opt/tomcat/webapps/MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use getResourceAsStream and suck it up off of my class path. Flat file names are problematic inside of web applications.